# Template Run version Different from Debug

Tags: c++, templates, runtime-error

I have an object like the following

```
template<typename T> 
inline void UnusedParameter( T const& )
{

}

class Client
{
public:
  template<class T>
  void runFFT(T *wSamples, float const &fMult)
  {
    std::cout << "INSIDE RUNFFT : : :" << std::endl;
    UnusedParameter(wSamples);
    UnusedParameter(fMult);
  }
};
```

And in my CPP I have the following:

```
#include "object.hpp"

template<>
void Client::runFFT<int16_t>(int16_t *wSamples, float const &fMult)
{
  std::cout << "INSIDE INT16_T version: : :" << std::endl;
  UnusedParameter(wSamples);
  UnusedParameter(fMult);
}

template<>
void Client::runFFT<Ipp32f>(Ipp32f *wSamples, float const &fMult)
{
  std::cout << "INSIDE IPP32F version: : :" << std::endl;
  UnusedParameter(wSamples);
  UnusedParameter(fMult);
}
```

Both these implementation run without any problem in my Debug Code. It enters the int16_t version without problem and the Ipp32f version also without problem.

But when I try the Run version it only enters the Template, like the compiler only compiles the Template implementation in the header.

How do I prevent this from happenning? Shall I remove this and just create two different methods? I love my templates but these Heisenberg bugs are frustating.

Thanks for any input.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Andy Prowl answered this question and it is solved doing the following in the HPP:

```
template<typename T> 
inline void UnusedParameter( T const& )
{

}

class Client
{
public:
  template<class T>
  void runFFT(T *, float const &)
  {
    // Thanks for Joachim for removing my Unused Parameter crap
    std::cout << "INSIDE RUNFFT : : :" << std::endl;
  }
};

template<>
void Client::runFFT<int16_t>(int16_t *wSamples, float const &fMult);

template<>
void Client::runFFT<Ipp32f>(Ipp32f *wSamples, float const &fMult);
```

And now it works in runtime as well. The CPP stays the same.

Comment: A small tip: If you don't want the "unused argument" warnings, just declare the type but not the name. Like `void runFFT(T *, float const &)`

Comment: Is `AnalyzerClient` a subclass of `Client`?

Comment: As for your problem, a debugger normally clears all variables, even local variables. This means that you might have a `NULL` check which succeeds in the debugger but fails when you don't run in the debugger. To solve this make sure you initialize all variables properly, like setting pointers to `0` (or `NULL` or `nullptr`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip Joachim! I always hated my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely in the fact that you relegated the specializations of your member function `runFFT()` for `int16_t` and `Ipp32f` in a separate `.cpp` file without providing a corresponding declaration after the primary template, so the compiler at the point of instantiation (which likely belongs to another translation unit that `#include`s only the header file containing the definition of `Client`) doesn't know about the existence of those explicit specializations.

Put a *declaration* for those specializations in the same header file that contains the definition of your class template:

```
template<typename T> 
inline void UnusedParameter( T const& ) { }

class Client
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void runFFT(T *wSamples, float const &fMult)
    {
        std::cout << "INSIDE RUNFFT : : :" << std::endl;
        UnusedParameter(wSamples);
        UnusedParameter(fMult);
    }
};

// DECLARE YOUR EXPLICIT SPECIALIZATIONS HERE

template<>
void Client::runFFT<int16_t>(int16_t *wSamples, float const &fMult);

template<>
void Client::runFFT<Ipp32f>(Ipp32f *wSamples, float const &fMult);
```

Per Paragraph 14.7.3/6 of the C++11 Standard:

> If a template, a member template or a **member of a class template** is explicitly specialized then that specialization
>   shall be **declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation
>   to take place**, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; **no diagnostic is required**. [...]

The "*no diagnostic is required*" part means that if you don't follow this rule, your program will be ill-formed, but your compiler/linker is not required to tell you. This normally results in the kind of undefined behavior you are observing.

Comment: No, this will give a "multiple definition of `void Client::runFFT<float>(float*, float const&)" error. Template specializations go in the CPP file. Compiled with GCC 4.3.3

Comment: @Claudiordgz: Correct, sorry. I meant to write "put a declaration for those specializations". If you don't do that, the compiler won't be aware of their existence